# Problem with gray alpha mask on fur texture

Tags: texturing, transparency

I have a problem with enabling transparency on a texture. Some parts of the model i'm working with are fur and should have transparency, however, the alpha channel of the dds texture isn't black&white but grey with the furry parts in white and the default cycles setup for transparency does not work here. Also, i can see the the alpha channel only in Photoshop; it's entirely white in the Blender UV-Editor. Here's what the alpha channel looks like:

[image]

Link to the original dds-texture:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/7o6298d07ptre03/texture.dds

Answer (score 1):

If you run that fur mask through ColorRamp grey will be remapped  to black and almost white - to white. If default interpolation modes aren't enough (eg. on *Linear* or *Ease* modes background won't be made fully black without the rest becoming too dark and hence invisible when used as mask) then change *Linear* to *Constant*. Adjust color stops a bit so fur details become visible:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that non-fur parts become invisible too, causing holes in the mesh, because this approach uses "color" instead of alpha as a factor. So i tried using the ColorRamp on the Alpha output, but that did not do anything.

Comment: @MasterBates edit your question with any additional info, for now the problem isn't quite clear. If non-fur parts become invisible then factor is not made like in the screenshot above (e.g. interpolation is Linear). Alpha output from the setup above surely will be white since the image doesn't have any alpha.